# how to convert moment to custom format string in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have moment object, and I want to convert it to string with the format `dd.mm.yy`. What's the best way to do this with moment.js?

I tried toString function, but it returned date in the format of `Wed Mar 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200` and it's too much effort to convert it manually.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to convert moment object to the format you prefer. In your case:

```js
var momObj = moment();
var timeToString = momObj.format('DD.MM.YY');
console.log(timeToString);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[moment.js lib](http://momentjs.com/) the reference to the moment js lib, the only lib you need to work with time!

```
var momentObj = moment(); // will take now time and date as moment object
var formatDate = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss"; // the string that represents desired format.

var result = momentObj.format(formatDate);
//result will be string "04.07.2016 12:25:12"
```

Comment: First you should not answer a partial question. Second, if you do, please explain what you have done, so it can help others as well